# Leaflet with GoogleMutant doesn't load tiles when moving or zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

In the head the following code:

```html
<html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/dist/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>

    <script>
    var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<my-api-token>';

    var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
            id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            attribution: mbAttr
        }),
        streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            attribution: mbAttr
        });

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [45.38, 7.88],
        zoom: 12,
        layers: [streets]
    });

    var google = L.gridLayer
        .googleMutant({
            type: "satellite", // valid values are 'roadmap', 'satellite', 'terrain' and 'hybrid'
        });

    var baseLayers = {
        "Grayscale": grayscale,
        "Streets": streets,
        "Google": google
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When I load the page and I select the "Google" layer, the tiles are loaded correctly, but if I move or zoom the new tiles are not loaded. The other layers work correctly.

If I add the line `google.addTo(map);` at the end of the script, the google layer is shown on top of the streets layer, but still it doesn't load the new tiles when I move or zoom.

Comment: Is `google.addTo(mymap);` a typo?  If not, what is `mymap`?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. I've added the stacksnippet, but since my api-keys are restricted to my domain, it doesn't work so well. Anyhow, if you select the Google layer you can see the problem (in fullpage mode).

Comment: How do you get to "fullpage mode"?  I don't see the issue when I move or zoom the map in the code snippet (when I select "Google", the google tiles are still visible when I zoom out, and when I move the map), but I don't see anyway to make the code snippet "fullpage".

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps API defines a variable named `google` in the [`Window` global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object). GoogleMutant depends on that variable being defined and valid.

By doing `var google = L.gridLayer.googleMutant(...)`, you're effectively redefining that variable.

Use any other variable name.